# facebook php sdk logs out of website but does not logout of facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, logout

I have read many questions in a similar area to this and after reading about 20+ my problem is not discussed.

I have a web app using facebook login via the facebook SDK.
This is working fine on the website side of things.

However when using the `getLogoutUrl( )` the users are not logged out of facebook.

I have done both destroying the facebook session (via the destroySession method) before and after (in the redirected page) accessing the getLogoutUrl link and I am still logged into facebook.

The user is not longer logged into my site but facebook remains unchanged.
I would expect that when a user accesses the link provided by getLogoutUrl that they would be logged out of facebook. However all that happens is the user is redirected back to the site and the user is still logged into facebook.

So my websites side of things works fine. But providing the facebook logout link implies that they are logged out of facebook and can walk away. 
Where as in reality the users accounts is still logged in on facebook.

Why is this happening?
I cannot control facebook so I do not know what else I can do other than forwarding to the user to the logout link provided by getLogoutUrl.

I am using Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.2)

Comment: You you still have a valid user access token at the point when the user clicks the logout link?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. How do I know if I have a valid access token? I'm would say I do. I run the facebook destorySession on the return page after the user has visited the logout link.

Comment: Just output it right before you generate the logout link (`$facebook->getAccessToken`), and check it using the debug tool. A valid user access token is a requirement for successful logout of facebook.com.

Comment: Yes a token is returned and the token is included in the logout URL.